# Telethon: delete a message

Tags: python, telegram

I am trying to delete a message using telegram API and [Telethon](https://lonamiwebs.github.io/Telethon/).

Here is my code:

```
from telethon import InteractiveTelegramClient
from telethon.tl.types.input_peer_channel import InputPeerChannel
from telethon.tl.functions.messages.delete_messages import DeleteMessagesRequest

#...
total_count, messages, senders = client.get_message_history(
                        chat, limit=1)
msg = messages[0]

result = client.invoke(DeleteMessagesRequest([msg.id]))
```

But first of all nothing happens, and second, it doesn't look right, since msg.id is like 5 or 220 and it doesn't look like a unique number.

Here is the message:

```
msg: (message (ID: 0xc09bexxx) = (out=None, mentioned=None, media_unread=None, silent=None, post=True, id=5, from_id=None, to_id=(peerChannel (ID: 0xbdddexxx) = (channel_id=1234)), fwd_from=None, via_bot_id=None, reply_to_msg_id=None, date=2017-06-14 14:39:23, message=test33, media=None, reply_markup=None, entities=None, views=1, edit_date=None))
```

I also tried with the hex number 0xc09bexxx but that gives an exception.

So how can I delete a message in a channel?

So far I looked at this [github issue](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/issues/20) to get started with the delete message. My guess is that maybe the following import is not the right one and I should import the version in the Channels package, which gets a channel id and a message id?

```
from telethon.tl.functions.messages.delete_messages import DeleteMessagesRequest
```

Comment: https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/client.html#telethon.client.messages.MessageMethods.delete_messages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the other delete from channels package I was able to get the delete message working, but I am still curious to know how to get the delete from **messages.delete_messages** working.

```
from telethon.tl.functions.channels.delete_messages import DeleteMessagesRequest

channel = InputPeerChannel(channel_id, access_hash)
result = client.invoke(DeleteMessagesRequest(channel, [msg.id]))
```

and it will delete the message from the channel.

Answer (score 2):

For example if u want to obtain all the msgs-ids in the channel and after of it delete all messages... this code works to me:

```
from telethon import TelegramClient

client = TelegramClient('cookiename', Apiid, 'api_hash')
id_group = -XXXX

async def getmsgs(client,id_group):
     messagesid = []
     async for message in client.iter_messages(id_group):
         print(message.id)
         messagesid.append(message.id)
     return messagesid

async def delmsgs(client,id_group,list_msgs_id):
     await client.delete_messages(entity=id_group, message_ids=list_msgs_id)

with client:
     messages = client.loop.run_until_complete(getmsgs(client,id_group)) 
     client.loop.run_until_complete(delmsgs(client,id_group,messages))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from telethon import TelegramClient

client = TelegramClient('cookie', '123', 'XXX')

id_group = -1001231231231

id_message = 3

await client.delete_messages(entity=id_group, message_ids=[id_message])
```